# Is java that secure?

Tags: java

Will the fact that java class files can be decompiled and need of third party software for obfuscation in any way compromise security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no... yes, if you compile any sorts of passwords into your Java program that you distribute, then yes, it will not be secure, but then again, this would be a terrible thing to do in any programming language... for example, in C++, you can recover strings that have been compiled into the program using the [strings](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings) utility.

If there is any super secret thing that you do, then you should generally not distribute the JAR that  does that super secret thing (although "security by obscurity" is generally not secure). While there are certainly basic things that you need to know about security, and it is possible to shoot yourself in the foot with Java, the fact that Java can be decompiled really is not a major security disadvantage. I should also note that, in general, you are less likely to experience security woes in Java given that Java protects you from out-of-bounds memory accesses, buffer overflows, dangling pointers, and other pointer manipulation problems.

Answer (score 12):

Only if you actually rely on security through obscurity, which is a bad idea regardless of the language or platform.

If the code can be run, it can be reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 6):

Java security is mostly about protecting your machine from malicious code.

Not about protecting code from reverse-engineering.

Answer (score 5):

"if it runs, it can be cracked" (in the context of say anti piracy measures in a game)

Answer (score 2):

My simple opinion is that nothing in computing is 100%

Therefore, is something is created, that something can also be broken.

Comment: 100% what? I'm assuming you meant "secure".

Comment: that correct, so pretty much 100% nothing, unbreakable and all the other un's. That i meant is that something such as eg."this program can never be hacked"

Answer (score 2):

No, security is fine.

You're right, compiled Java code can be easily audited. However, building security schemes based on the assumption that no one will ever know how it works (no one will see the code) is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes class file can be decompiled for some extent. But you will not get the exact code after decompiling as so many constants, literal values etc.. will be directly substituted in the compiled class

Answer (score 1):

Decompiling is basically a method to rewrite the code based on the by code.Yes it is a security threat so it is best to avoid sensitive information in the Java class. As far as the logic is considered, given time any application's logic can be guessed without actually decompiling it.

Decompiling Java class is easy because java stores high level information to maintain portability.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reflect into a class file and see a lot of data, not everything is available or compiled in to the class file and even more is just compiler sugar.